# How can i add content to the head section of prestashop so it appears where the hookHeader is located?

Tags: module, header, prestashop

I am new to Prestashop and programming and I am trying to add some content to Prestashop 1.4.5.

I made a new simple module that hooks to the hookHeader. I got it working and it shows Hello World in the top of the shop. But when i open the site and open the source code I see it is added before the the doctype:

Hello World

My module php looks like this - I am not using a template:

if ( !defined( '_CAN_LOAD_FILES_' ) )
    exit;

class primanetskintop extends Module {

```
function __construct()
{
    $this->name = "skintop";
    $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
    $this->version = '0.1.0';
    parent::__construct();
    $this->displayName = $this->l('Insert skin top');
    $this->description = $this->l('Skin - ikke slettes');
}

function install()
{
   if (!parent::install() OR !$this->registerHook('header'))
            return false;
    return true;    
}

function uninstal()
{
    if (!parent::uninstall())
        return false;
    return true;
}

public function hookHeader($params) 
{
    echo "Hello World!";
}
```

Why does the hello world not show where the hookHeader is located? What am i doing wrong?

Thank you :D

Answer (score 2):

It's because you can't use echo to add content to the header. Try:

```
public function hookHeader($params) 
{
    return "Hello World!";
}
```

You may want to analyze FrontControler.php from the classes dir to understand how this works.